# Build opencv_contrib Modules fail with xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, opencv

I first use `opencv-3.0.0-rc1` with `Xcode(7.3)` to build `opencv.framework`, it works ok , but When I add with with `opecv_contrib` it fails.

My `Xcode` version is `xcode7.3` and I use following code to build the framework:

```
python build_framework.py --contrib opencv_contrib ios_contrib
```

the result:

[image]

I have try to remove the dnn module from the `opencv_contrib` ,but it will show that other module in the `opencv_contrib` build fail.

Does anyone know why ?

Comment: CompileC platforms/ios/ios_contrib/build/iPhoneOS-arm64/modules/xphoto/OpenCV.build/Release-iphoneos/opencv_xphoto_object.build/Objects-normal/arm64/grayworld_white_balance.o platforms/ios/opencv_contrib/modules/xphoto/src/grayworld_white_balance.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)